# Why does Magento 2 new theme from scratch has many js files included?

Tags: magento, magento2

I am just beggining to learn Magento and would like a thougrogh explanation if possible.

I just created a new theme from scratch with *NO* parent theme, and I found many JS and two CSS files included by default.

Here is a sample:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
      href="http://192.168.1.9/magento/pub/static/version1495681460/frontend/btata/themeone/en_US/mage/calendar.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"
      href="http://192.168.1.9/magento/pub/static/version1495681460/frontend/btata/themeone/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"
      href="http://192.168.1.9/magento/pub/static/version1495681460/frontend/btata/themeone/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico">
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://192.168.1.9/magento/pub/static/version1495681460/frontend/btata/themeone/en_US/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://192.168.1.9/magento/pub/static/version1495681460/frontend/btata/themeone/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://192.168.1.9/magento/pub/static/version1495681460/_requirejs/frontend/btata/themeone/en_US/requirejs-config.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://192.168.1.9/magento/pub/media/styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery"
        src="http://192.168.1.9/magento/pub/static/version1495681460/frontend/btata/themeone/en_US/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_"
        data-requiremodule="jquery/jquery.mobile.custom"
        src="http://192.168.1.9/magento/pub/static/version1495681460/frontend/btata/themeone/en_US/jquery/jquery.mobile.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="js/responsive"
        src="http://192.168.1.9/magento/pub/static/version1495681460/frontend/btata/themeone/en_US/js/responsive.js"></script>
```

My questions are:
1- Do I have to keep those files?
2- If not, how to remove them?
3- Why are some of them missing? see picture.
[Missing files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G6ko.jpg)

Thanks